# match partial string in List<string> in another List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list, match

its me. i got the following code:

```
foreach (var str in usedCSS) { 
    if (CSS.Any(c => c.IndexOf(str)>0))        
        Response.Write(str + "<br />"); 
    else        
        Response.Write("Could not find: " + str + "<br />"); 
}
```

`usedCSS` = `List<string>`

`CSS` = `List<string>`

but, i need it the other way around...

i want the `var str in usedCSS` to be `var str in CSS`

`usedCSS` contains strings of only the css names e.g: `.header`

`CSS` contains string of the actual css e.g: `.header {font-size:14px;}`

basicly, what i need is to print out the actuall CSS that is used.
The code i currently have does the exact opposite, it returns only the css names,
not the actuall css.

Comment: That's probably the most horrific smiley I've seen in my life. ( ;) )

Comment: lol, would that prevent you from answering ?

Comment: k, i removed it, will you help me now ?   ( ;) )

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question, but I'm having some trouble... what kind of object is `usedCSS`? What kind is `CSS`?

Comment: added it to the original question. hope it will help.

Comment: just an observation... wouldn't you want >= 0 in case it starts with it?

Comment: do you need code to distinguish `.header` from `.header1`?

Comment: I mean if css contains `".header1 {fsldfkjsl}"` string and your usedCss: `".header"`. Should algorithm return success match result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what it is you're trying to do correctly, you could do this.  `FirstOrDefault()` finds the first occurrence of a predicate match and returns it, or `null` (default for type `string`) if not found.  Then all we need is the `StartsWith()` string method to match each item in CSS prefix-wise with the `str` in question.

```
        foreach (var str in usedCSS)
        {
            // FirstOrDefault finds first match or returns default (null for string) if not found.
            var match = CSS.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith(str));

            if (match != null)

                // get the match.  
                Response.Write(match + "<br />");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Could not find: " + str + "<br />");
            }
        }
```

p.s.  The above works if you only expect one or no matches, if you can have multiple matches, and want them all:

```
foreach (var str in usedCSS)
{
    foreach(var match in CSS.Where(s => s.StartsWith(str)))
    {
        // get the match.  
        Response.Write(match + "<br />");
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a case that was similar to the OP. The lists were not exactly the same. Many of the other answers on stack overflow would give me tons of dupes. However using the firstordefault got rid of dupes. An excellent response. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var R = (from str in CSS from x in usedCSS where str.StartsWith (x) select str).ToList();
foreach ( var V in R )
{
    Response.Write ( V.ToString() + "<br />");
}
```

Comment: can you convert that to lambda expression ? i hate using the `from` thingy's. and i cant understand it that way 8)

Comment: I am not really fluent with lambda expressions... sorry.

Comment: lol, and me the opposite. if no other answer will come up i will award you the correct answer.

Comment: I posted an answer using a lambda, but keep in mind they are essentially the same.  He's just using the LINQ query language and I'm calling the LINQ extension methods with a lambda.  Also I look for first match where he returns all matches, but you could do either approach depending on what you want (first or all).

Comment: well, im so used to lambda expression, i dont even understand the Linq Query.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<string> result = CSS.Where(a => usedCSS.Any(b => b.IndexOf(a) >= 0)).ToList();
        result.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
```

and the reverse

```
        List<string> result = usedCSS.Where(a => CSS.Any(b => a.IndexOf(b) >= 0)).ToList();
        result.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
```

Sample code...

```
        List<string> CSS = new List<string>() { "hello", "goodbye" };
        List<string> usedCSS = new List<string>() { "hello darlin", "when are you available", "hello chief", "what", "when to say goodbye" };
        List<string> result = usedCSS.Where(a => CSS.Any(b => a.IndexOf(b) >= 0)).ToList();
        result.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

result:

```
hello darlin 
hello chief 
when to say goodbye
```

or

```
        List<string> CSS = new List<string>() { "hello", "goodbye" };
        List<string> usedCSS = new List<string>() { "hello darlin", "when are you available", "hello chief", "what" };
        List<string> result = CSS.Where(a => usedCSS.Any(b => b.IndexOf(a) >= 0)).ToList();
        result.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

result:

```
hello
```

Comment: well, i wouldnt say it dosent work if it was... since i DO need a solution, after trying your code, i got nothing printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more "archived" solution:

```
List<string> list = css.Where(c => usedCss.Any(c.Contains)).ToList();
```

You can check, using this test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> css = new List<string>
            {
                ".header {font-size:14px;}",
                ".foo {dfsfd}",
                ".foobar",
                ".wefw"
            };

            List<string> usedCss = new List<string>
            {
                ".header",
                ".foo",
            };

            List<string> list = css.Where(c => usedCss.Any(c.Contains)).ToList();

            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Has found in:");
                list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            }
            else
            {
                usedCss.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("Could not find: " + x));
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Pay attention, that such code could not distinguish `'.foo'` from `'.foobar'`. In general case if it meters you should use more complicated check with regular expressions.